# Creating a custom feed for categories that includes the first post's featured image

Tags: categories, feed

I'm needing a little help getting this figured out. I have a query that's not quite working right now, but I need it to create a custom feed that includes category information and then includes the featured image from the first post in that category.

Anyone have thoughts on how to get that running?

```
/**
 * Custom Feed for Category Listing
 */
    function outputXMLFeed()
    {
        echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
        echo '<items>';
        $args=array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $categories=get_categories($args);
        $posts = get_posts(array('category' => $category->term_id));
        foreach($categories as $category) { 
            echo '<item>';
            echo '<catID>' . $category->term_id . '</catID>';
            echo '<catname>' . $category->name . '</catname>';
            echo '<postcount>' . $category->category_count . '</postcount>';
            echo '<slug>' . $category->slug . '</slug>';
            echo '<featured>' . [VARIABLE HERE] . '</featured>';
            echo '</item>';
        }
        echo '</items>';
    }
    add_action('init', 'add_my_feed');

    function add_my_feed(  ) {
      add_feed("myFeed", "outputXMLFeed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a function to return the first post of a category by a given category ID ex:

```
function get_category_post($cat_id){
    $post_args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'category' => $cat_id,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    );
    $posts = get_posts($post_args);
    return $posts[0];
}
```

Then, once you have that function you can use it like this:

```
function outputXMLFeed()
{
    echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
    echo '<items>';
    $args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $categories=get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo '<item>';
        echo '<catID>' . $category->term_id . '</catID>';
        echo '<catname>' . $category->name . '</catname>';
        echo '<postcount>' . $category->category_count . '</postcount>';
        echo '<slug>' . $category->slug . '</slug>';
        echo '<featured>' . get_the_post_thumbnail(get_category_post($category->term_id) , $size = 'post-thumbnail') . '</featured>';
        echo '</item>';
    }
    echo '</items>';
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_feed');

function add_my_feed(  ) {
  add_feed("myFeed", "outputXMLFeed");
}
```

Comment: Ok, cool. I've got all that put in place, but for some reason it's still not outputting all the individual items within the <items></items> tag. Thoughts?

Comment: working just fine on my end https://gist.github.com/4428853

Comment: Can this only run in a plugin? I've been trying to set it up through the functions.php

Comment: No, it should run from functions.php as well

Comment: Strange, this is the only output I'm getting: http://sandboxdewsly.com/?feed=myFeed. This is on a multi-site setup, should that have any affect on it?

Comment: Wait a second, sorry to waste your time with the wrong question. This is probably working, but none of my categories have articles in them at the root site of the network. Is there a way to have this feed for each site on the network? Right now it's redirecting to the root site...